# Long code into function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, scrollto

This code has no errors in my page, so I'm not looking for any help there. I'm just curious if there is a shorter way to do this, there's a lot of code being repeated with just some class names being changed each time. Could I make this shorter in a function or loop of some sort? Thanks

```
//menu
            $('.aboutOne').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.basicsRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.basicsRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })
            $('.aboutTwo').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.storyRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.storyRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })
            $('.aboutThree').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.teamRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.teamRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })

            $('.aboutOne').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.basicsRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.basicsRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })
            $('.aboutTwo').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.storyRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.storyRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })
            $('.aboutThree').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.teamRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.teamRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })
            $('.titleOne').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.homeRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.homeRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })
            $('.docsOne').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.startRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.startRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })
            $('.docsTwo').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.pinpointRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.pinpointRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })
            $('.docsThree').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.swipeRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.swipeRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })
            $('.docsFour').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.restRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.restRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })
            $('.docsFive').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.actionRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.actionRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })
            $('.contactOne').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.contactRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.contactRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })
            $('.downloadOne').click(function(){
                $.scrollTo('.downloadRow', 1000, {axis:'yx'});
                $.scrollTo('.downloadRow', 1000, {axis:'xy'});
            })
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The HTML would be helpful too.

Comment: I am sure if it is a typo or not, but you have the elements `.aboutX` repeated twice

Comment: ha! you're right, I do. oops

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps put everything into an object, then pass to a function:

```
var els = {
     '.aboutTwo':'.teamRow',
     '.aboutThree':'.homeRow',
     ...
};

function menu(els){
     $.each(els, function(a,b){
         $(a).click(function(){
            $.scrollTo(b, 1000, {axis: "yx"});
            $.scrollTo(b, 1000, {axis: "yx"});
         });
     });
}

// Call it
menu(els);
```

Should give you the most manageability - if anything changes you just modify the `els` object.

NOTE: Would like to take this opportunity to point out it's suggested you use jQuery's `.on()` ([Docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) for binding events.

Comment: This does not work for some reason.

Comment: @AlexTheGoodman, well, you can try [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14943705/417685) or [Blazemonger's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14943692/417685) which both provide some interesting possibilities

Comment: @Fluidbyte, `.on()` is used internally by `.click()`

Comment: @AlexTheGoodman - should work now - here's a fiddle that shows an alert since I don't have your HTML - http://jsfiddle.net/fluidbyte/9LvEz/

Answer (score 1):

I would add [`data-`](http://api.jquery.com/data) attributes to each clickable element to specify what you want it to scroll to:

```
 <a class="clicktoscroll aboutOne" data-row="basicsRow">...</a>
```

Now you just need one event handler:

```
        $('.clicktoscroll').click(function(){
            var $row = $(this).data('row');
            $.scrollTo('.' + $row, 1000, {axis:'yx'});
            $.scrollTo('.' + $row, 1000, {axis:'xy'});
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `data-*` attribute, let's say `data-scroll-to`, and let your elements control where you want to scroll to instead.

```
<button class="about" data-scroll-to=".basicsRow">Button</button>
```

For example,

```
$("[data-scroll-to]").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), target = $this.data("scroll-to");
    $this.click(function() {
        $.scrollTo(target, 1000, { axis: 'yx' });
        $.scrollTo(target, 1000, { axis: 'xy' });
    });
});
```

Comment: If you put a hyphen inside a `data` attribute, the jQuery argument should be camelCased (as of jQuery 1.6): `$(this).data("scrollTo");`

Comment: @Blazemonger, our answers are exactly alike. Guess who post it last :|

Comment: @Blazemonger, by the way, jQuery does the transformation by itself